# from ideals to elements

Tags: number-theory

For a number field $K$, an ideal of $\mathcal O_K$ factors uniquely into prime ideals.

Let $\alpha = \sqrt[3]7, K = \mathbf Q(\alpha)$. Then we have the following factorizations:

$(2) = (2, \alpha^2 + \alpha + 1)\cdot(2, \alpha + 1)$

$(3) = (3, \alpha - 1)^3$

$(5) = (5, \alpha^2 - 2\alpha - 1)\cdot(5, \alpha + 2)$

$(7) = (\alpha)^3$

and so on.

How does one use this data to factor *elements*?

Which primes are inert, which ones split, and which ones ramify? If a prime doesn't "stay prime" in $K$, how can we compute its factorization?

I am more or less familiar with what happens in quadratic extensions and was curious about the cubic case.

---

Searching with Sage, I found some factorizations:

$41 = (2\alpha^2 + 7\alpha + 4)\cdot(\alpha^2 - 2)$

$71 = (\alpha^2 - 4\alpha + 16)\cdot(\alpha + 4)$

$83 = (4\alpha^2 - 6\alpha + 9)\cdot(2\alpha + 3)$

$113 = (4\alpha^2 - 7\alpha - 16)\cdot(\alpha^2 + 4)$

I am wondering how to find these numbers more systematically.

Comment: There need not be a factorization of elements. In $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$, the ideal $(3)$ is a product of two prime ideals, but $3$ is irreducible. As to figuring put which primes are inert, split, ramify, if the ring of integers is of the form $\mathbb{Z}[a]$ for sone $a$, then the factorization of $(p)$ "looks like" the factorization of the minimal polynomial of $a$ in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Is there a way to check if a prime factors into elements in a number field?

Comment: If the ideal it generates factors as a product of principal ideals. Note that if the ring of integers is not a PID/UFD, then there *necessarily* are irreducible elements that are not prime (and in particular the principal ideal they generate  factors, but the element does not).